# Question about subadditive functionals

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Def: Let $X$ be a vector space. $f$ is called a subadditive funcional in $X$ is $f$ is a functional(real - valued) and it satisfies :

$$f(x + y ) \leq f(x) + f(y) \; \; \; \forall x,y$$

Question: Suppose $f$ is a subadditive functional on a normed space $X$. Say $f(x) > 0 $ for all $x \notin \{ x : ||x|| = r \} $. Then, can we conclude that $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in X $ ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conclusion does not hold, take $f(x) = \|x\|$.